# Java array sorting not work

Tags: java

I'm new on Java, I have array problem, I try writing array sorting method but I can't success,  please correct me, I want sort array high to low:

```
public static int[] sirala(int[] arr){
    int[] yeni = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length-1;i++){
        if(arr[i+1] > arr[i]){
            yeni[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        else{
            yeni[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return yeni;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are only looping once - there is no way you can sort looping over data only once... (well, there is, but let's ignore that for now)

Comment: I looping input array length so not once time ?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pen; then examine what your algorithm does and how you can fix it. All algorithms start with pen and paper...

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I'll try :)

Comment: Imagine your input array was 1,2,3,4,5.  Your output would be: 2,3,4,5,0.  If your input was 1,2,1,2,1 your ouput would be 2,2,2,2,0.    You can, as Boris mentioned, write out some values like that on paper, and run through your algorithm by hand, to see what the errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your method `sirala` like this one below.You have to use two loops inner loop will take out the largest element to the front of the array (largest number will be shifted to `0` index , 2nd largest will be shifted to to `1` index and so on...),then simply you have to assign it to the `yeni` array's respective element after inner loop.

```
public static int[] sirala(int[] arr)
{
        int[] yeni = new int[arr.length];
        //shifting ith largest element to (i-1)th pos of arr
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j< arr.length;j++){
                if(arr[j] > arr[i]){
                    int tmp=arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j]=tmp;
                }
            }
            //assigning element to new array
            yeni[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return yeni; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.I explained how code works with comments:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int [] array){
    //Creating boolean value for verify that array has been sorted.
    boolean isSorted=false;

    //You should execute your method until array sorted.
    while(isSorted==false){
        //Assign true value to isSorted.
        isSorted=true;

        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
            //if array has not been sorted yet.if statement will be executed and isSorted will become false.
            //This makes while loop executed until array sorted
            if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
                int temp=array[i];
                array[i]=array[i+1];
                array[i+1]=temp;

                isSorted=false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can get it sorted in more simpler syntexed way. If you like javascript. Have look in this.

```js
function sort(arr){
   var len = arr.length;
   for (var i = 0; i<=len-1; i++){
     for(var j = i+1; j<=len-1; j++){
       if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
          var temp = arr[i];
           arr[i] = arr[j];
           arr[j] = temp; 
        }
     }
   }
   return arr;
}

console.log(sort([7,5,2,4,3,9])) // your choice of data//
alert(sort([7,5,2,4,3,9]))
```

Comment: Javascript is to Java as cat is to caterpillar.